# GNU Readline: how to treat CamelCaseWords as multi-word?

Tags: readline, camelcasing

I would like my word-boundary-based readline bindings to treat CamelCaseWords as multi-word.

For example, I would like to need three 'forward-word' actions to get from one end to the other in "CamelCaseWords". Can it be done?